# Customer Data Account using Intuit

Tags: php, jquery, ruby-on-rails-3, intuit-partner-platform, customer-account-data-api

I am trying to use Customer Data Account API though php. i have fetched all accounts by passing this for demo account such as 100000 cc-Bank account but its on Intuit.

Banking Userid
            demo
        
        
            Banking Password
            go

i want to get fetch Api url data of fetched account at client side by php i have found missing OAuth->fetch method i have made it.But its not working at my side.

i have also followed https://github.com/jrconlin/oauthsimple but its only working for to get Institutions details and list.

If anybody has an idea please help me out.

Answer (score 0):

I tried this call using java devkit and it worked fine.

You can refer the following PHP example which is available in IPP's site.

https://github.com/pleslie/phpaggcat/

IPP Doc - https://developer.intuit.com/docs/0020_customeraccountdata/devkits

Hope it will be useful.

Thanks